# Как перейти из корня в конкретную DB в рамках одного Connection

Tags: java, postgresql

Я устанавливаю соединение с корнем DB :

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                this.property.getRootDB(),
                this.property.getUsername(),
                this.property.getPassword());
```

После некоторых действий с корнем я хочу перейти к конкретной базе сделать `\c my_database` но так как все скрипты я храню в файле `Property` то символ `\` мне портит всю картину.

Нельзя ли перейти к базе еще как-то? Так что-бы не прерывать соединение?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5630778/2908793 если не сработает setCatalog, то можно обернуть все во враппер, который будет выполнять перед каждым запросом смену базы данных, либо и вовсе конструировать новый датасорс после того, как наличие базы было подтверждено.

Comment: @etki похоже это не для postgres(((